# How to create a dropdown list from a json object?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What am I doing wrong here? (probably everything).  I'd like 'foo' to come up as the selection and the value when selected to be 1.  The error I get is 'Objects are not valid as a React child'.

```js
constructor(props) {
     this.state = {options: {name: 'foo', value: 1}};
  }

 render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <select>{this.state.options}</select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is options going to be an array of `{ name, value }` objects? Not really sure how the current data structure translates to options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you'd want your options to be an array of objects. Then in your render function, do something like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {options:[{name: 'foo', value: 1}]};
}
render() {
  return <div>
    <select>{this.state.options.map(function(item) {
      return <option value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>;
    })}</select></div>
}
```

Comment: made options an array of object and implemented your code.  It doesn't bomb out anymore, but the list is empty.

Comment: Does your constructor look like this?:

    constructor(props) {
      this.state = {options: [{name: 'foo', value: 1}] };
    }

Comment: Check out my latest edit, I think you need the call to `super(props)` in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

**`#1:`** You absolutely don't need to store these options in your component's `state`.

**`#2:`** Replace your object with an array and use `Array#map` to render each option.

```js
render() {
  const options = [{ name: 'foo', value: 1 }]
  return (
    <select>
      {options.map(option =>
        <option value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
      )}
    </select>
  )
}
```

Comment: Great advice!  I do NOT need to store the values in a state.